# Pagination, scrolling, and potential library conflicts

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, pagination

I'm trying to get the following event fired :

`$(window).on("scroll", function(){ alert("test"); });`

I've done some researching and I believe that it must be conflicting with one of the other libraries I'm currently using (**jQuery mobile, jQueryUI, jQueryUI Touch Punch** and trying to implement Sausage).

So my question is, how can I detect why this isn't firing the alert (in Chrome)?

Comment: if at all there is some error , you can check in the console and resources

Comment: I've checked the console and resources, and I'm not seeing any errors

Comment: please study [this](https://api.jquery.com/scroll/)

Comment: Yes, thank you. I have already.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Jquery's scroll function:

```
$( window ).scroll(function() {
   alert('Test');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L0absaw5/

Comment: I've tried both, and to my understanding there's effectively no difference between the two in the basic way I'm implementing it

Comment: I don't know what goes wrong, but I made a fiddle with this code and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/L0absaw5/

Comment: Yea it works in the sausage.js demo I have locally as well. But when I put it into the project I'm working on, no go. So that's my question, how can I debug the conflict?

Comment: Could you post your complete code in a fiddle? Using alert() or console.log() are good debug practices for debugging javascript.

Comment: I can't, it's under NDA

Comment: First thing I would try to find out is if jquery works, try $( 'body' ).html('Hello World!'); if this doesn't work your jquery is not loaded properly.